# Segment tree with lazy propagation - Multiply all values in a range

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree, range-query

I have the following code which for segment tree with lazy propagation which I could manage to write. This code does not work for **multiplying all numbers in a range with a value, say x. I think I am doing something incorrect in the update_mult function.** The tree maintains the sum of a range.

I could not figure out the problem with the update_mult. Experts, could you help me find out where am I going wrong with the implementation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <set>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <time.h>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i<b;++i)
#define FORR(i,a,b) for(int i=a;i>=b;--i)
#define FORC(it,container) for(typeof(container.begin()) it=container.begin();it!=container.end();++it)
#define INT(x) scanf("%d",&x)
#define LLD(x) scanf("%lld",&x)
#define STR(x) scanf("%s",x)
#define CHAR(x) scanf("%c",&x)
#define PINT(x) printf("%d\n",x)
#define PLLD(x) printf("%lld\n",x)
#define CLR(x) memset(x,0,sizeof(x));

const int INF = INT_MAX;
const int MAX = 1000001;


typedef long long LL;

LL arr[MAX+5];
LL MOD = 1e9 + 7;

struct data
{
    LL sumsq;
    LL sum;
    LL lazyset;
    LL setval;
    LL lazyMult;
    LL lazyVal;
    LL addval;

    void assignleaf()
    {

    }
    void assignleaf(int idx ,int val)
    {

    }

    void combine(data &l, data &r)
    {
        sum = (l.sum + r.sum)%MOD;
    }
};

data tree[10*MAX+5];

void pushdown(int node,int segs,int sege)
{
    int mid = segs+sege; mid /= 2;

    if(tree[node].lazyset==1)
    {
            tree[node].lazyset=0;

            tree[2*node].lazyset=1;
            tree[2*node+1].lazyset=1;

            tree[2*node].setval = tree[node].setval; 
            tree[2*node+1].setval = tree[node].setval;

            tree[2*node].sum = ((mid-segs+1)*tree[node].setval)%MOD;
            tree[2*node+1].sum = ((sege-mid)*tree[node].setval)%MOD;

            tree[2*node].addval=0;
            tree[2*node+1].addval=0;

    }

    if(tree[node].lazyMult==1)
    {
            tree[node].lazyMult=0;

            tree[2*node].lazyMult=1;
            tree[2*node+1].lazyMult=1;


            tree[2*node].sum = (tree[2*node].sum  * tree[node].lazyVal)%MOD;
            tree[2*node+1].sum = (tree[2*node+1].sum  * tree[node].lazyVal)%MOD;

            tree[2*node].addval=0;
            tree[2*node+1].addval=0;
    }

    if(tree[node].addval)
    {

            tree[2*node].addval = (tree[2*node].addval +tree[node].addval)%MOD;
            tree[2*node+1].addval = (tree[2*node+1].addval +tree[node].addval)%MOD; 

            tree[2*node].sum = (tree[2*node].sum + ((mid-segs+1)*tree[node].addval)%MOD)%MOD;
            tree[2*node+1].sum =(tree[2*node+1].sum+ ((sege-mid)*tree[node].addval)%MOD)%MOD;

            tree[node].addval = 0;
    }   
}

void build_tree(int node,int s,int e)
{
    tree[node].addval=0;
    tree[node].lazyset=0;

    if(s>e) return;

    if(s==e)
    {
        tree[node].sum = arr[s];
        return;
    }

    int mid=(s+e)/2;

    build_tree(2*node,s,mid);
    build_tree(2*node+1,mid+1,e);

    tree[node].combine(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]);

}

LL query(int node,int segs,int sege,int qs,int qe)
{

//cout<<" q -- node = "<<node<<" segs = "<<segs<<" sege = "<<sege<<" qs = "<<qs<<" qe =  "<<qe<<endl;


    if(segs>sege || segs>qe || sege < qs) 
    {
        if(tree[node].lazyset||tree[node].addval)
             pushdown(node,segs,sege);

        return 0;

    }

    if(tree[node].lazyset || tree[node].addval)
        pushdown(node,segs,sege);

    if(segs>=qs && sege<=qe)
    {

    //cout<<"q1 node = "<<node<<" segs = "<<segs<<" sege = "<<sege<<" sumsq  = "<<tree[node].sumsq<<endl;
        return tree[node].sum % MOD;

    }

    int mid= segs+sege; mid /= 2;


    return (query(2*node,segs,mid,qs,qe) + query(2*node+1,mid+1,sege,qs,qe))%MOD;

}

//comm=1
void update_add(int node,int segs,int sege,int qs,int qe,int x)
{

    if(segs>sege||segs>qe||sege<qs) return;

    if(segs>=qs && sege<=qe)
    {
        tree[node].addval = (tree[node].addval+x)%MOD;
        tree[node].sum   = (tree[node].sum + ((LL)(sege-segs+1)*x)%MOD)%MOD;
        return;
    }

    int mid= segs+sege; mid /= 2;

    if(tree[node].lazyset || tree[node].addval)
        pushdown(node,segs,sege);

    update_add(2*node,segs,mid,qs,qe,x);
        update_add(2*node+1,mid+1,sege,qs,qe,x);

    tree[node].combine(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]); 


}

void update_mult(int node,int segs,int sege,int qs,int qe,LL x)
{

//cout<<" ua -  node = "<<node<<" segs = "<<segs<<" sege = "<<sege<<" qs = "<<qs<<" qe =  "<<qe<<" x = "<<x<<endl;


    if(segs>sege||segs>qe||sege<qs) return;

    if(segs>=qs && sege<=qe)
    {
        //tree[node].addval = (tree[node].addval * x)%MOD;
        tree[node].sum   = (tree[node].sum * x)%MOD;
        tree[node].lazyMult = 1;
        tree[node].lazyVal = x;
        tree[node].addval = 0;
        return;
    }

    int mid= segs+sege; mid /= 2;

    if(tree[node].lazyMult || tree[node].addval)
        pushdown(node,segs,sege);

    update_mult(2*node,segs,mid,qs,qe,x);
        update_mult(2*node+1,mid+1,sege,qs,qe,x);

    tree[node].combine(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]); 


}

//comm=0
void update_set(int node,int segs,int sege,int qs,int qe,LL x)
{

    //cout<<" node = "<<node<<" segs = "<<segs<<" sege = "<<sege<<" qs = "<<qs<<" qe =  "<<qe<<" x = "<<x<<endl;

    if(segs>sege||segs>qe||sege<qs)
        return;


    if(segs>=qs && sege<=qe)
    {
        tree[node].lazyset= 1;
        tree[node].setval=x;
        tree[node].sum   = ((LL)(sege-segs+1)*x)%MOD;
        tree[node].addval = 0;
        return;
    }

    if(tree[node].lazyset || tree[node].addval)
        pushdown(node,segs,sege);


      int mid= segs+sege; 
      mid /= 2;


     update_set(2*node,segs,mid,qs,qe,x);
     update_set(2*node+1,mid+1,sege,qs,qe,x);

    tree[node].combine(tree[2*node],tree[2*node+1]);


}





int main()
{

    int test = 1;

    FOR(tt,1,test+1)
    {
        int n,q; INT(n); INT(q);


        CLR(arr);
        CLR(tree);

        FOR(i,0,n)
            LLD(arr[i]);

        build_tree(1,0,n-1);

        while(q--)
        {
            int comm; int l,r; 

            INT(comm); INT(l); INT(r);


            if(comm==3)
            {
                //set x 
                LL x; LLD(x);       
                update_set(1,0,n-1,l-1,r-1,x);      

            }
            else if(comm==1)
            {
                //add x
                LL x; LLD(x);               
                update_add(1,0,n-1,l-1,r-1,x);

            }
            else if(comm==2)
            {
                //add x
                LL x; LLD(x);               
                update_mult(1,0,n-1,l-1,r-1,x);

            }
            else if(comm==4)
            {
                LL ans = query(1,0,n-1,l-1,r-1);

                PLLD(ans);

            }

        }

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is from an ongoing contest on [Codechef](http://www.codechef.com/JULY15/problems/ADDMUL). Please do not ask questions from ongoing contests. You could read the editorial after the contest is completed, and should remove this question now and re-ask then.

Comment: **Moderator notice**: Questions about on-going contests are not off-topic for Stack Overflow. Moderators can and will not police third-party agreements and that includes contest rules. It is up to the contest to discipline or police their rules. Please do not flag this post just because it is about a CodeChef contest.

Comment: Voting to close, not because of any past or present contest, but because "does not work" does not describe either the specific error or problem encountered, nor the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the order of the blocks of code in pushdown function.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiply how can you set  addval of child to 0. In case of initialization it is ok because now any multiplication and addition becomes redundant but not in case of multiply.In case of multiplication you can't do so because you have still to add that value. Moreover I think that order of addition and multiplication may also come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Try this test case, you will figure out your mistake:

4 10

1 3 4 5

1 1 2 1

4 1 4

2 1 3 4

4 1 4

3 2 4 2

4 1 4